# WARNING:Xst:1290: - Hierarchical block <uut2> is unconnected in block <top>. It will be removed from the design

Tags: verilog

Here is my code of top module and rom module. I don't find any error in this, but it is showing this error and I don't know why.

```
module top (clk,clr, ss, mosi,sck);
  input clk;
  input clr;
  output ss;
  output mosi;
  output sck;

  wire [10:0]address;
  wire[7:0]data;
  wire done,start,mclk,clk_out;

  clock uut1(.clr(clr),.mclk(clk),.clk_out(clk_out)); 
  ROM_Memory uut2(.address(address),.data(data));
  ctrl uut3 (.clr(clr),.clk(clk_out),.address(address),.data(data),.start(start),.done(done)); 
  spi uut4 (.clk(clk_out),.clr(clr),.data(data),.start(start),.done(done),.ss(ss),.mosi(mosi),.sck(sck));
endmodule
```

ROM module-

```
module ROM_Memory(address,data);
  input [10:0] address;
  output [7:0] data;

  reg [7:0]ROM[0:1034];

  initial begin
    $readmemh("preeti.txt",ROM);
  end

  assign data = ROM[address];
endmodule
```

It is showing rest three modules in RTL schematic and simulation is also running fine.

Comment: $readmemh is synthetizable for Xilinx FPGA. It's not an error anyway, but a warning

Comment: What module consumes the data you generate with your ROM? And what module generates the address needed to address your ROM? Check the modules that are actually connected to the ROM for misnamed signals. Your ROM may be connected to `top` but if it is the only thing that is connected, it will be thrown away by the optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `top` module serves as a framework to connect things one each other.

Your system seems to be a controller that reads a ROM and sends its contents thru SPI. The ROM is effectively connected in `top`, but your module only shows that there are a pair of buses (`address` and `data`) which ROM is connected to. We don't know if those buses are connected to somewhere else. They should be, but if `ctrl` or `spi` don't use `address` or `data` (because of a mispelled name, for example), the ROM will actually be connected to nowhere.

Add this to the beginning of every Verilog file in your design, so you can catch any error caused by a mispelled signal name:

```
`default_nettype none
```

Another cause of your ROM being disconnected from your design is that the file you provide to initialize it is not complete. If your ROM has 1035 cells, all of them must be initialized, or else, the synthesizer will throw away the `ROM` register, and hence, the complete `ROM_Memory` module will be thrown away as well.

To ensure that your ROM is totally initialized, modify your initial block to add these lines:

```
integer i;
initial begin
  for (i=0;i<=1034;i=i+1)  // Prefill all the ROM, so you can use an incomplete file later
    ROM[i] = 8'h00;
  $readmemh("preeti.txt",ROM);  // Initialize up to 1035 cells from preeti.txt
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot , ROM is partially initialized and that was the cause of this problem .after initializing it totally code is running without warning.